# IDENTITY NOT NULL at Table Creation

Tags: sql, null, identity

Can anyone please tell me whether the instruction `IDENTITY NOT NULL` at a table creation is redundant or not? I mean, judging by the message

DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

I would say that any column declared as `IDENTITY` is implicitly also declared as `NOT NULL`, but I would like to make sure. Can anyone please confirm?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The question seems to be, "If something is implied, is explicitly declaring it 'redundant'?" The answer would appear to be subjective. Is declaring `NOT NULL` on a column comprising the `PRIMARY KEY` redundant? If the `NO ACTION` referential action is always redundant, why does it exist at all?

Answer (score 11):

SQL Server adds NOT NULL constraint to identity columns automatically eventhough he did not speficy it when creating a table

Consider the following table script

```
create table test(id int identity(1,1), name varchar(1000))
```

Now Generate the script of the table from Management Studio. It generates the script as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Eventhough NOT NULL constraint is not specified in the table script by default it is added. The identity column will never be NULL. So NOT NULL constraint is added default

Comment: If you do not specify NULL or NOT NULL, SQL will set an identity column as NOT NULL. Me, I'd always specify it, to avoid the confusion endemic to the existance of the `SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF` and `SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` commands.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server (2008, and probably earlier versions as well) will not allow you to create an identity column on a NULL column. Try it:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo1
 (
   FooId  int  identity not null
  ,Data  varchar(20)  not null
 )
```

works, where

```
CREATE TABLE Foo2
 (
   FooId  int  identity null
  ,Data  varchar(20)  not null
 )
```

generates error message `Could not create IDENTITY attribute on nullable column 'FooId', table 'Foo2'.`

Comment: Ultimately your answer sort of implies that NOT NULL is sort of implied. :)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that later, after adding the comment to @Pranay's post. My overall take on coding is to always avoid using "implicit code". Never assume that SQL will do what you think it **ought** to do, but rather take the extra effort (of, say, typing in "not null") to be clear in the directions you give to the computer.